# A tour of alternative spellings

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, language

English spelling is notoriously difficult and inconsistent. Let's try some alternatives for a size, shall we?

> Ö spelling das not häv tu bi båring. Vi kän ålvejs improv it baj ädding sam nu interesting letters.
>
> Z is sacz an anjuzd letter. Wi szud juz it macz mor, szud wi not?
>
> Haŭ abaŭt sam leterz vit litel hats? Ĉek it aŭt! A pleĵur tu luk at, ŝurli ju agri.
>
> Īven džast streit lains ken bī priti kūl. Īzier tu rait kompērd tu hets, et līst?
>
> Kiųt litel huks ander leters? Aim sould! Hąrd tu dizegrį vit sač en edišen. Or ąr tei not jor kap of tį?
>
> Sín eny speling jů supórt jet? Perhaps jůl inkaunter jór pryférd van ivenšaly.
>
> Giv mí mór äkszent márksz! Du vi häv tu csúsz? Kän vi not häv tem ól?
>
> Jüüsing tuu leters tu indikeit long saunds is samting vii niid tu düü moor! Düü jüü not ägrii?
>
> Háo dù yú láikè tīsī tàipè? Měibì tū hārdè fór yú? Ài làik yītè kuàitè ā luótè!
>
> Wiçever speliň wî çûz, îç haz its benefits. Eniwey, hier endz awr tûr of alternativ Iňliş speliňz!

Looking for a one-word answer.

Comment: (ROT13) *"Naljnl, urer raqf bhe gbhe bs nygreangvir [fbzrguvat] fcryyvatf."* What is that something?? Hmm...

Comment: Alternative English Spelling @user477343

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Ahhh, English :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Each of these lines

> mimics the spelling of some other language.

In order, these are:

> Swedish, Polish, Esperanto, Latvian, Lithuanian, Czech, Hungarian, Estonian, Chinese (romanized with Pinyin), Kurdish

which gives

> **SPELLCHECK** from the first letters of each language.

Comment: Looks like (ROT13) guvf nafjre zvtug nyfb trg n purpx! How on Earth did you...?

Comment: For some reason, Google Chrome is offering me to translate from (ROT13) ivrganzrfr...